# What are the advantages of an instrumentation amplifier over a single op amp amplifier?

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, instrumentation-amplifier

Basically, strain gauges are going to be connected to a Wheatstone bridge and the output from the bridge will be amplified by an instrumentation amplifier. But what are the advantages of this over a single op-amp amplifier?

Comment: Wikipedia has a pretty good rundown of the advantages. With strain gauges the voltages are small, so you need adequate gain, you don’t want to feed offset currents back into the bridge and you want good CMRR as the voltages of interest can be swamped by noise.

Comment: They don't call 'em "instrumentation amplifiers" for no reason....

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a bridge there are two inputs which are both similar source impedance, so an instrumentation amplifier may make sense to measure the difference in voltage. The high impedances on both inputs mean that the gain is isolated from any changes in the absolute value of the resistances.

Downsides include more complicated saturation characteristics, (all other things being equal) more front end noise by (ideally) about 40%, more complexity etc.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It is very detailed

Comment: @SulavRai feel free to upvote this answer when you find it useful.

Comment: Although the increased front end noise by \$\sqrt 2\$ is valid, the total noise of an inamp can often be lower than a single opamp difference amplifier. Actually I consider SNR an advantage of Inamp vs DiffAmp. The reason is that both the gain stage and the difference stage can use much lower valued resistors in an Inamp. The noise advantage of the DiffAmp would only really apply to very low source resistances of a few Ohms.

Comment: @tobalt Had a design where it applied at much higher resistances, more like tens of thousands of ohms. Can you guess why? :-)

Comment: I would be interested to know. My guess would be you were power or space constrained and thus couldn't use low valued discrete resistors. Anyway, at impedances of 10s of kOhm and above, the noise of the resistors will gradually be the main contributor to noise.

Comment: @tobalt The bulk of the resistance was close to abs zero temperature. This also changes the trade-off with current noise. Something like \$\text {1pA}\sqrt{\text {Hz}}\$ becomes dominant over a low voltage noise front end.

Comment: But unless the whole Diff Amp (including feedback resistors) is cool, too, the feedback resistors will dominate noise. My point about low source resistance was because larger source resistances would require larger feedback resistors too (irrespective of temperature), unless a sizable gain error is acceptable or compensatable. Anyway, if youre interested we can continue in chat, but I don't know how to begin a chat :)

Comment: I don't do chat, but consider a non-inverting op-amp amplifier with a 5K and 10 ohm feedback network (gain = 501). Thermal noise of <10\$\Omega\$ is not much (input-referred noise voltage). Input impedance on the non-inverting input is high.

Answer (score 0):

The main thing that sets them apart from a single opamp difference amplifier configuration is its extremely high input impedance for high source impedances.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!